# ¿Cómo corregir este error TypeError not subscriptable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

```
[LOGS] Logs loaded successfully.

line 1192, in createMessge
    message = f' Daily report {today} (N: {ARGS.wfd[0]})\n\n'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

```
parser.add_argument('--d',
                         metavar=('<API_TOKEN>'),
                         nargs=1,
                         help='[Optional] Discord webhooks', 
                         type=str, 
                         required=False)
parser.add_argument('--wfd',
                         metavar=('<WF_NAME>'),
                         nargs=1,
                         help='[Optional] Workflow name and run number', 
                         type=str, 
                         required=False)

def createMessge():
     today = date.today().strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
     message = f' Daily report {today} (N: {ARGS.wfd[0]})\n\n'
```

**(N: {ARGS.wfd[0]})\n\n'** cuando pongo el argumento **--d** que sirve para crear un mensaje y enviarlo a discord, este codigo me tira error. como lo puedo anular?

Este codigo sirve para enviarme el deploy.yml que se ejecutó en ese momento

```
Ejemplo GITHUB ACTION:
Daily report 07/12/2022 (N: deploy-1)
Daily report 07/12/2022 (N: deploy-2)
```

Comment: Pues al parecer el valor de `ARGS.wfd` es `None` debes empezar por averiguar por que pasa eso.